Flutter auto-router can not created by command
flutter part 'app_router.gr.dart' not creating  with command. should i create myself manually
I'm currently using Mac and i export path but now working. I tried
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs command but it is not create the file
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:weather_app/ui/screens/home_screen.dart';

@MaterialAutoRouter(
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
    MaterialRoute(page: HomeScreen, initial: true)

  ],
)
class $AppRouter {}

import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:weather_app/core/di/service_locator.dart';
import 'app_router.gr.dart';

void main() {
  setupLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final _appRouter = AppRouter();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerDelegate: AutoRouterDelegate(
        _appRouter,
        navigatorObservers: () => [AutoRouteObserver()],
      ),
      routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(),
    );
  }
}


Share the detail code, It should generate the router file automatically

i added the code

it is not generate it

Check your auto_route version and @MaterialAutoRouter is deprecated. See: migration-to-v6
Updated:
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:de_weather/src/presentation/screens/home/home_screen.dart';


part 'app_router.gr.dart';

@AutoRouterConfig()
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {

//Default route type 
  @override
 RouteType get defaultRouteType => const RouteType.material(); //.cupertino, .adaptive

  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
        /// routes go here
        AutoRoute(page: HomeScreen.page)
      ];
}

Add @RoutePage annotation on you HomeScreen class.
@RoutePage()
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}

and run command
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

main.dart

void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  final _appRouter = AppRouter();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: AppTheme.light,
      routerConfig: _appRouter.config(),
    );
  }
}


